# How to compare user input in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I'm writing a simple script and I cant seem to get it to work.
It throws a error at the if statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Whats your name ?"
read NAME

if [$NAME == "SSJ" ]
then
  echo "Welcome back SSJ"
fi
```

Comment: You are missing a space `[ $NAME == "SSJ" ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Whats your name ?"
read name

if [ "$name" = "SSJ" ]
then
  echo "Welcome back SSJ"
fi
```

Comment: `==` breaks compatibility with other shells, use `=` to do string comparison.

Comment: yeah, but this one is specificly for bash

Comment: The OP _can_ use the `==` operator for string comparison, but you should use the `[[ ... ]]` test construct. Thanks to it, you don't have to quote `$NAME` even if it can possibly contain spaces. So I suggest: `#!/bin/bash; echo "Whats your name ?"; read name; if [[ $name == "SSJ AL" ]]; then echo "Welcome back SSJ AL"; fi`

You can try without the `[[ ]]` but keeping the space in the pattern to match, so that you can see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Whats your name ?"
read NAME

if [ "$NAME" == "SSJ" ]; then
  echo "Welcome back SSJ"
fi
```

Comment: Better yet, don't use CAPITAL variable names and don't use `==`.